# Running a sh file in git bash even results in variable assignment statements being shown in terminal

Tags: windows, bash, git, sh

I am trying to run a sh file on git bash on Windows 10. I am even seeing the statements which I don't want to be shown like variable assignment in the console. But the same stuff I can't see on either Windows Subsystem for Linux(WSL) or other linux distributions. It becomes a bit annoying to see all the code lines in the sh file when trying to run that, when I am only interested in seeing the statements which I want to echo. Can someone please help in this ?

Sample sh file :

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
VARIABLE="OK"
echo $VARIABLE
```

> Output on git bash:

[image]

> Output on WSL(or any other Linux Systems):

[image]

Comment: Note that bash-for-Windows is not actually part *of* Git. It's packaged *with* Git in various distributions because Git needs it, but you can install *just* bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That only happens when both of these occur:

1. `set -x` is used
2. `PS4` is set

If you fix either one, the messages will go away.

If you want to fix number one, you can do `set +x`, or you can find the file that
is calling `set -x` and remove that line. Probably `~/.bash_profile` or
`~/.bashrc`.

If you want to fix number two, you can do `PS4=`, and you can add it to one of
those files above to persist if you want.